# i need help solving inequality

Tags: inequality

I need help solving  this inequality $x^2+5x-2 < 0$. 
Im not sure where to even begin with this problem, so no attempts have been made

Comment: Find the roots of $x^2+5x-2=0$ and draw the graph to get an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Find the roots of the quadratic polynomial $x^2+5x-2=0$ either by guessing or by using the fact that the solutions are of the form $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$ where $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ (assumming the standard notation $ax^2 +bx+c=0$). In these roots are exactly the points where the polynomial changes it's sign. What is the sign of the polynomial when $x\to \pm\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

use the formula $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ In your case: $a=1$, $b=5$, and $c=-2$ .Then you pick the values between the two $x$ you find with the above formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+5x-2<0$$
the roots of $$x^2+5x-2=0$$ are $x_{1}=\frac{-5+\sqrt{33}}{2}$ and $x_2=\frac{-5-\sqrt{33}}{2}$ 
and because quadratic function $$y=f(x)=x^2+5x-2$$
has minimum below $x$ axis we conclude that $$x\in\left(\frac{-5-\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{-5+\sqrt{33}}{2}\right)$$ is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I need to solve the inequality $y(x)=x^2+5x-2<0$. Here is what I did. Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

$D=5^2-4\cdot(-2)=25+8=33$

$x=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{D}}{2}=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{33}}{2}$

$x_1=\frac{\sqrt{33}-5}{2}$

$x_2=\frac{-\sqrt{33}-5}{2}$

It is clear to see that $x_1>0$ and $x_2<0$

-----$x_2$------$0$------$x_1$------

If we use $x=0$, then we see that $y(0)=-2<0$. It means that in $[x_2, x_1]$, $y(x)$ is less than zero. So, every value of x in $\left[\frac{-\sqrt{33}-5}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{33}-5}{2}\right]$ is the solution of $x^2+5x-2<0$ inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+5x-2=\frac{(2x)^2+2\cdot2x\cdot5+5^2-33}4=\frac{(2x+1)^2-33}4=\frac{(2x+1+\sqrt{33})(2x+1-\sqrt{33})}4$$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2+5x-2<0\iff(2x+1+\sqrt{33})(2x+1-\sqrt{33})<0$

Now, the product of two terms is negative, so the multiplicands must be of opposite parity

Demonstrate that $\displaystyle2x+1+\sqrt{33}>0$ and $2x+1-\sqrt{33}<0$